# Dynamically download files from Artifactory depending on wildcard condition

Tags: curl, wget, artifactory

I have a loop that would upload one or more files to artifactory as per below:

```
    if [ "${consider_kinds}" = "all" ] || [ "${consider_kinds}" = "serviceaccounts" ]
            then
                    echo "Uploading source serviceaccounts"
                    cd "${HOME}"/sync-cluster/${consider_namespace}/serviceaccounts || exit
                    for file in *.yaml
                    do
                            if [ -e "$file" ]
                            then
                                    curl --user "${deploy_user}:${deploy_user_password}" -XPUT "https://testcompany.com.au/test-virtual-repo/sync-cluster/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -T "${file}"
                                    break
                            fi
                    done
            fi
```

Filename would be like this:

```
${BUILD_NUMBER}-${source_cluster}-${consider_namespace}-${resource}-${item}.yaml
```

Sample file names could be like this:

```
120-ntive-src-cluster-sit1-serviceaccounts-default-hssjjs.yaml
120-ntive-src-cluster-sit1-serviceaccounts-pod-labeller-abc.yaml
```

So, how to list the remote files(0 or 1 or more) and then download them is my question?

Had it been just a single file, I could have downloaded like below:

```
wget "https://testcompany.com.au/test-virtual-repo/sync-cluster/${BUILD_NUMBER}-${source_cluster}-${consider_namespace}.json"
```

What I don't know is how to download them dynamically! :(

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved using the JFrog CLI together file specs or AQL and by using placeholders.
There are multiple examples for such a scenario in the JFrog CLI [official doc](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadCommandSpecSchema).

Comment: I know about that but we do not have jfrog cli installed again because of one of many reasons, and also deployments coming so I need to use curl. Is there any way to do it by curl?

Comment: That's not an issue - You can still use curl to run AQL queries to search for the artifacts per your search criteria and then download them based on the path given.
See relevant documentation:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#Artifactory

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language